# mysql 5.7.16 on linux server is too slow compare with mysql 5.6.16-log on localhost

Tags: mysql

**localhost:**

```
innodb_version  5.6.16
protocol_version    10
slave_type_conversions
version 5.6.16-log
version_comment MySQL Community Server (GPL)
version_compile_machine x86
version_compile_os  Win32
innodb_buffer_pool_size  3221225472
```

**Server Centos:**

```
innodb_version  5.7.16
protocol_version    10
slave_type_conversions
tls_version TLSv1,TLSv1.1
version 5.7.16 version_comment  MySQL
Community Server (GPL)
version_compile_machine x86_64
version_compile_os  Linux
innodb_buffer_pool_size  3221225472
```

I have the following query:

```
select 
    t1.TICKET, 
    t1.PRODUCT,
    t1.CMD,
    t1.SIZE,
    t1.LOGIN_ID,
    t1.CREATE_TIME d1 ,

    t2.TICKET,
    t2.PRODUCT,
    t2.CMD,
    t2.SIZE,
    t2.LOGIN_ID,
    t2.CREATE_TIME d2 ,

    ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,t1.CREATE_TIME,t2.CREATE_TIME)) 

from  (select LOGIN_ID, CREATE_TIME, PRODUCT, TICKET, SIZE, CMD from orders where CREATE_TIME between '2016-01-01' and '2016-01-05') t1,
      (select LOGIN_ID, CREATE_TIME, PRODUCT, TICKET, SIZE, CMD from orders where CREATE_TIME between '2016-01-01' and '2016-01-05') t2
where
     t1.LOGIN_ID <> t2.LOGIN_ID
    and t1.CMD <> t2.CMD
    and t1.PRODUCT = t2.PRODUCT
    and t1.SIZE = t2.SIZE
    and ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,t1.CREATE_TIME,t2.CREATE_TIME)) < 60;
```

when I executed this query on localhost it took about 0.3 sec, but when I executed it on the server it took 3000+ seconds.
(same table structure and same rows count and same indexing)
(both tables are optimized)

The target to find any 2 orders with same **size** & **product** & different **CMD** added to the system in the same minute.

any idea why the server takes that time to execute the query?

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `TICKET` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `LOGIN_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `PRODUCT` char(16) NOT NULL,
  `CMD` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `SIZE` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CREATE_TIME` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`TICKET`),
  KEY `INDEX_LOGIN_ID` (`LOGIN_ID`),
  KEY `INDEX_CMD` (`CMD`),
  KEY `INDEX_CREATE_TIME` (`CREATE_TIME`),
  KEY `INDEX_PRODUCT` (`PRODUCT`),
  KEY `INDEX_PRODUCT_LOGIN_ID_SIZE` (`LOGIN_ID`,`PRODUCT`,`SIZE`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

Explain Query - Localhost:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN select 
    t1.TICKET, 
    t1.PRODUCT,
    t1.CMD,
    t1.SIZE,
    t1.LOGIN_ID,
    t1.CREATE_TIME d1 ,

    t2.TICKET,
    t2.PRODUCT,
    t2.CMD,
    t2.SIZE,
    t2.LOGIN_ID,
    t2.CREATE_TIME d2 ,

    ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,t1.CREATE_TIME,t2.CREATE_TIME)) 

from  (select LOGIN_ID, CREATE_TIME, PRODUCT, TICKET, SIZE, CMD from orders where CREATE_TIME between '2016-01-01' and '2016-01-05') t1,
      (select LOGIN_ID, CREATE_TIME, PRODUCT, TICKET, SIZE, CMD from orders where CREATE_TIME between '2016-01-01' and '2016-01-05') t2
where
     t1.LOGIN_ID <> t2.LOGIN_ID
    and t1.CMD <> t2.CMD
    and t1.PRODUCT = t2.PRODUCT
    and t1.SIZE = t2.SIZE
    and ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,t1.CREATE_TIME,t2.CREATE_TIME)) < 60;
+----+------------+-----------+-------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-------------------+-------+-------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type  | possible_keys       | key                | key_len | ref               | rows | Extra             |
+----+------------+-----------+-------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-------------------+-------+-------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY   | <derived2> | ALL  | NULL               | NULL               | NULL    | NULL              |     2 | NULL              |
|  1 | PRIMARY   | <derived3> | ref   | <auto_key0>        | <auto_key0>        | 52      | t1.PRODUCT,t1.SIZE |     2 | Using where       |
|  3 | DERIVED   | orders    | range | INDEX_CREATE_TIME | INDEX_CREATE_TIME | 5       | NULL              |     1 | Using index condition |
|  2 | DERIVED   | orders    | range | INDEX_CREATE_TIME | INDEX_CREATE_TIME | 5       | NULL              |     1 | Using index condition |
+----+------------+-----------+-------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-------------------+-------+-------------------+
4 rows in set

mysql>
```

Explain Query - Server:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN select 
    t1.TICKET, 
    t1.PRODUCT,
    t1.CMD,
    t1.SIZE,
    t1.LOGIN_ID,
    t1.CREATE_TIME d1 ,

    t2.TICKET,
    t2.PRODUCT,
    t2.CMD,
    t2.SIZE,
    t2.LOGIN_ID,
    t2.CREATE_TIME d2 ,

    ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,t1.CREATE_TIME,t2.CREATE_TIME)) 

from  (select LOGIN_ID, CREATE_TIME, PRODUCT, TICKET, SIZE, CMD from orders where CREATE_TIME between '2016-01-01' and '2016-01-05') t1,
      (select LOGIN_ID, CREATE_TIME, PRODUCT, TICKET, SIZE, CMD from orders where CREATE_TIME between '2016-01-01' and '2016-01-05') t2
where
     t1.LOGIN_ID <> t2.LOGIN_ID
    and t1.CMD <> t2.CMD
    and t1.PRODUCT = t2.PRODUCT
    and t1.SIZE = t2.SIZE
    and ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,t1.CREATE_TIME,t2.CREATE_TIME)) < 60;
+----+------------+--------+----------+-------+----------------------------------+--------------------+---------+--------------------+-------+--------+-------------------+
| id | select_type | table   | partitions | type  | possible_keys                     | key                | key_len | ref                | rows | filtered | Extra             |
+----+------------+--------+----------+-------+----------------------------------+--------------------+---------+--------------------+-------+--------+-------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE     | orders | NULL     | range | INDEX_CREATE_TIME,INDEX_PRODUCT | INDEX_CREATE_TIME | 5       | NULL               |     1 |    100 | Using index condition |
|  1 | SIMPLE     | orders | NULL     | ref   | INDEX_CREATE_TIME,INDEX_PRODUCT | INDEX_PRODUCT     | 48      | test.orders.PRODUCT |     1 |    100 | Using where       |
+----+------------+--------+----------+-------+----------------------------------+--------------------+---------+--------------------+-------+--------+-------------------+
2 rows in set

mysql>
```

Comment: Perhaps because your server is executing 1001 other queries at the same time? Please post full details including table strcutures, explain analyze etc

Comment: this is development server and nothing run on this server at all and only me has access

Comment: Please post full details including table strcutures, explain analyze etc

Comment: I updated the post with more details

Comment: well according to your explain you are not running the same query on the two servers

Comment: same query copy and paste but different explain output

Comment: Check the `optimizer_switch` system variable on each server. [MySQL 5.6::8.9.2 Controlling Switchable Optimizations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/switchable-optimizations.html) and [MySQL 5.7::9.9.2 Controlling Switchable Optimizations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/switchable-optimizations.html).